# How can I delete specific rows and columns in a given matrix for C++?

Tags: c++, matrix, search, vector, erase

I have a multidimensional `vector` of `chars`, and I want to be able to delete a specific column or row on command. For example, if I had this matrix:

```
A B C D
L K T M
A M T N
```

Deleting the second column would change the matrix to

```
A C D
L T M
A T N
```

Then, deleting the third row would change the matrix to

```
ACD
LTM
```

My code that I have written for this purpose currently returns an error for both row and column deletions:

```
void verticalSearch(vector< vector<char> >matrix, int startIndex, int lengthWord, string word)
{
    for(int k = 0; k < matrix[0].size() ; k++) // iterating for each column
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.size() - lengthWord + 1; i++) // for each row
        {
            char c;
            string s = "";
            for (int j = startIndex; j < startIndex + lengthWord; j++) // this startIndex is always 0
            {  // but this for loop stands for iterating in a length of given word

                c = matrix[i + j][k]; // adding given index of matrix to character c
                s += c;

            }
            
            if (s == word) // if a specific word is founded
            {
                
                matrix[0].erase(matrix[0].begin() + k); // delete this column but not working correctly
                cout << "Word is founded" << endl;
                printMatrix(matrix); // And print it 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can somebody please tell me what's wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You have a vector of rows, therefore to delete a column you must delete one character from each row. You can write a loop to do this. E.g.

```
for (int row = 0; row < matrix.size(); ++row)
    matrix[row].erase(matrix[row].begin() + k);
```

**EDIT**

So your code should end up looking like this

```
if (s == word) // if a specific word is founded
{
    // delete a column            
    for (int row = 0; row < matrix.size(); ++row)
        matrix[row].erase(matrix[row].begin() + k);
    cout << "Word is founded" << endl;
    printMatrix(matrix); // And print it 
}
```

Comment: For my case of example it would be like this matrix[i].erase(matrix[i].begin()+k); i is the row number and k is the column index but it is still gave the same kind of error that print out just deleting a single column and rest is same

Comment: @Razbolt You are misunderstanding my answer. You need to replace `matrix[0].erase(matrix[0].begin() + k);` with the loop I've shown you. You need to add a new loop to your code.

Comment: @Razbolt You only delete one character exactly because you haven't written a new loop. If you want to delete a whole column, you need to do it with a loop.

Comment: @Razbolt I've editted the answer to show exactly what I mean.

Comment: Oh yes I understand what you mean and now ı got a problem vector subscrip out of range if ı wrote DMN in a given example at the end of column and also ı have this problem for the deleting a row and ı could not find a way to fix it

Comment: @Razbolt You have to be very careful if you are iterating through a vector and shrinking it at the same time. You've probably made a mistake somewhere because of that. Remember that you are changing the size of your vector as you go round your loops.

Comment: Thanks a lot, yes you are right in above example with the help of you, now ı have 4 inside loops and it gaves an error just for the last ones 4 loops makes that more harder to find but ı will try my best thanks for advice !